# Problem with the author of a node revision and the Revisioning module

Tags: 6, nodes

I am using the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module for Drupal 6. When administrator users accept the node revision, the author name is changed to anonymous user.

Why does this happens?